# how to connect graphql Api to front End apps on nginx hosted on Ec2

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, graphql, next.js

I have an App composed of three projects with the following structure :

mainapp
        ->/packages

```
    ->/admindashboard
    ->/shopapp
    ->/api
```

- I want to deploy the project on an Ec2 instance (which I'm not the administrator), so I built the admindashboard and the shopapp with :
  `yarn build`
- added Nginx and configured the /nginx/sites-available/default file like so :

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   server_name localhost;
   location / {
         root /var/www/mainapp/packages/shopapp/out;
         index index.html index.htm;
   }
}

#running admin-Dashboard
server {
   listen 3000 default_server;
   server_name localhost;
   location / {
         root /var/www/mainapp/packages/admindashboard/build;
         index index.html index.htm;
   }
}
```

-this got the tow front apps to work, but I couldn't link the api.
when I run `yarn dev:api-shop or yarn dev:api-admin` 
it shows that it's running on port 4000 but the front app's fail to fetch the data, it can't get or post to the api.

**what is the correct way to deploy such project?**

the project technologies are  :

Admin Dashboard :
-CRA
-Apollo
-BaseUI
-Typescript
-React Hook Form

Shop :
-NextJs
-Apollo
-Typescript
-Styled Components
-Stripe Integration
-Formik

API :
-Type GraphQL
-Type ORM

thank you, and sorry if my explanation is not clear.

Comment: Can you paste how your UI App is trying to fetch data from the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem, actually in the admin project in the .env file the API URL was :

```
http://localhost:4000/admin/graphql
```

I had to change localhost to the Ip address of the instance like so :

(example)

```
http://15.xxx.xx.xxx:4000/admin/graphql
```

and it worked, yet having two API (one for the shop and one for the adminDashboard) 
I had to run one on the 4000 port and the other one on the 4001, Now it works but I still wonder if it's the proper way to deploy such app . thank you all